# PowerBI/DAX Measure as category for other measures

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have multiple simple calculated measures, which I would like to combine into categories, so that one could use this "category measure" in matrix visual.

Each measure basically counts data with some filter(s), like:

```
Blue = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNT(data[Full name]),
    FILTER(data, data[White/Blue] = "Blue")
    )
```

My attempt to this, was to create a table for measures categories, and then measure indexed accordingly.

Table:

```
Measures categories = 
DATATABLE (
    "Category", STRING,
    "Sub-Category", STRING,
    "Index", INTEGER,
    {
        { "Direct/Indirect", "Direct", 1},
        { "Direct/Indirect", "Indirect", 2},
        { "White/Blue", "White", 3},
        { "White/Blue", "Blue", 4}
    }
)
```

Measure:

```
Categories measure = 

VAR SelectedMeasure_ = 
    SELECTEDVALUE('Measures categories'[Index])

RETURN
    IF(HASONEVALUE('Measures categories'[Index]),
    SWITCH(
        SelectedMeasure_,
        1, [Direct],
        2, [Indirect],
        3, [White],
        4, [Blue]
    )
)
```

This seems to work fine, however I'm missing Totals in Matrix visual, how do I get sum of measures per category/subcategory and total? I can workaround this by adding additional Total fields with corresponding sums, but there must be a better way.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution, is to create another measure, which sums value of Categories measure.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).